# Keycloak use of securityCollections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

Somewhere I see peoples put this configuration to their Spring app:

```
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/testUser

keycloak.securityConstraints[1].authRoles[0]=offline_access
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/testAdmin
```

You can see that `securityCollections` index is always zero. My questions are:

1. What is `securityCollections` and what does it use for?
2. When do we have `securityCollections[1]`,
   `securityCollections[2]`, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keycloak's `securityCollections` configuration is like the Java EE `web-resource-collection` configuration, see [Easily secure your Spring Boot applications with Keycloak](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/05/25/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-keycloak#creating_a_simple_app):

> **Defining Keycloak's configuration**
>
> [...]
> Then we need to define some Security constraints as you will do with a Java EE app in your web.xml:
>
> ```
> keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
> keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/products/*
> ```
>
> Here, we simply define that every request to /products/* should be done with an authenticated user and that this user should have the role "user".

and [Securing Applications and Services Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter)

> **2.1.6. Spring Boot Adapter**
>
> [...]
> You also need to specify the Java EE security config that would normally go in the web.xml. The Spring Boot Adapter will set the login-method to KEYCLOAK and configure the security-constraints at startup time. Here’s an example configuration:
>
> ```
> keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] = admin
> keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[1] = user
> keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name = insecure stuff
> keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /insecure
>
> keycloak.securityConstraints[1].authRoles[0] = admin
> keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].name = admin stuff
> keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /admin
> ```

For more informations about `web-resource-collection`, see [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition: The Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier002.htm#GKBAA).

Comment: Hi @dur, thanks for your answer, but it's just about my first question. Could you please answer the second one?

Comment: @SoT The answer of your second question is: you could always use it, but you don't need to use it. It's just syntactic sugar.